# Google Maps's route view: What's the correct term for this "string of beads" element?

Tags: terminology, maps, transport

[image: String of beads?]

What would you call this vertical sequence of stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more specific than your question asks, but I would also consider that an **[itinerary UI](https://dribbble.com/tags/itinerary)**. Useful for conveying times, locations, and travel information in a timeline fashion (as stated by Pectoralis).

Answer (score 0):

**I would call it a vertical timeline.**

The "string of beads" is just googles way of showing the user that this is a distance he needs to walk instead of using public transportation etc.